# I am new to c# Windows programming... Please help me with following code error

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

```
void Dataadd()
{
        try
        {
            string connection = "Data Source=CD_PC\\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=example;Integrated Security=True";
            string query = "select * from student; ";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //MessageBox.Show("saved");
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string sName = rdr.GetString(""); 
                comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Error:

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Answer (score 1):

[`SqlDataReader.GetString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) takes `int` has a parameter (*zero based)* which column you want to read. Not `string`.

Pass this method your column number as integer you want to read. Let's say you want to read first column values and add them to `combobox1`.

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` like;

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
{    
   using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
     ....
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string sName = rdr.GetString(0); 
            comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So your error states the method `System.Data.Common.DbDataReader.GetString(int)` has invalid arguments.

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states, you need to pass an int value into it, not a string.

```
public abstract string GetString(
    int ordinal
)
```

Which in turn means, that his line `string sName = rdr.GetString("");` is wrong.
It should look something like `string sName = rdr.GetString(1);`

the int parameter states which column should be read. Now we do not know, which column you want, since you select `*` (everything), but if Id is your first column and Name is your second, you are looking for `.GetString(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Please, when asking a question, format your code out!

The immediate reason of your error is in the line

```
 string sName = rdr.GetString(""); // <- GetString requires int, that's Field's index
```

There're some other issues with your code:

1. Do not forget to dispose IDisposable instances (using(...) {...})
2. Do not catch ALL the exceptions withot re-throwing them

So something like that is expected:

```
void Dataadd() { // <- Probably DataAdd will be better name
  string connection = "Data Source=CD_PC\MSSQL;Initial Catalog=example;Integrated Security=True"; 

  // Format your code; let SQL be read as formatted SQL, not long, long line...
  string query = 
    "select *\n" +
    "  from student;"; 

  try {
    // Use "using" on IDisposable insatnces
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection)) {
      conn.Open();

      using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
        using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (rdr.Read()) { 
            string sName = rdr.GetString(0); // <- 0 stands for the 1st field; 

            comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);  
          }  
        }
      }
    }
  }
  catch (DataException ex) { // <- Never ignore ALL the exceptions: catch(Exception e) 
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx

SqlReader.GetString take an int as parameter and not a string ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
while (rdr.Read())
            {
                string sName = rdr[0]; // replace o with which column u want 
                comboBox1.Items.Add(sName);
            }
```

it will work